# External libraries XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, dll, external, xcode4.5

Can anyone please tell me how to link a library to a XCode 4.5 project?

I have to add the GMP library to a C++ project in order to use their multiprecision data types.

I've been stuck at this point for so much time and any comment would be great help...

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Howto is published at this link: [Linking GMP to Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955996/linking-gmp-to-xcode-4-5)