# Link External Library in Xcode C++ Project

Tags: c++, xcode7

I've found answers to this question, but they don't work for me.  I'm trying to build a C++ project in Xcode that uses external libraries from ffmpeg and openCV, and I can't figure out how to link them.  As recommended, I go the "Build Phases" screen, and there's a place for "Link Binary with Libraries."  One of the libraries I need to link with is at /usr/local/lib/libavutil.a.  When I try to add a library, a list box pops up showing two folders: "OS X 10.11" and "Developer Frameworks".  The library I need is not in either of these folders. I tried clicking on "Add Other" and a file chooser dialog comes up, but if I type "/usr/local/lib/libavutil.a" in the search box, the dialog doesn't accept it.

I've found that typing '-lswcale -lavcodec -lavdecice' etc. on the "Other linker flags" line in "Build Settings" works, but it's not what I hoped for.  I was hoping to get a file chooser dialog, where I could simply click on the libraries I want to use.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you simply want to "set" the file chooser dialog at the right place, right?

If so, you just have to press **Cmd + Alt + G** once you are in the file chooser dialog, after clicking on "Add Other..." in the "Link Binary with Libraries" menu. A "Go to the folder:" dialog comes up, and there you can type the fullpath to the file or the folder you are looking for.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Also, don't forget to include path to headers.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody else has provided a working answer, I am documenting that the only only thing I have found that works it to set the search paths for the libraries under "Library Search Paths" and then to add a -l flag for each library in the "Other Linker Flags" section, just as you would on the command line command line:[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955996/linking-gmp-to-xcode-4-5), you can try:

> 1) Open the left panel, goto "ProjectName", Targets, Build phases,
>   Link binary with libraries and select your library.
>
> 2) Open the left panel, goto "ProjectName", Project, Header Search
>   Paths, write the path where the headers of your library are (the .h
>   files, usually in /usr/local/include).
>
> 3) Open the left panel, goto "ProjectName", Project, Library Search
>   Paths, write the path where your libraries are (the .a or .dylib
>   files, usually in /usr/local/lib)

I hope you can confirm that this work for *Xcode7*.

On Step **1)** You can also:

- Under "Link Binary With Libraries", click on the plus button.
- Click "Add Other..." (this is a 3rd party library).
- Choose the filename (/usr/local/lib/libavutil.a).

P.S., I can't flag as a Dup, because [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955996/linking-gmp-to-xcode-4-5) was not an acepted answer

Comment: I've already done this, but it's insufficient.  This tells the linker where to look for libraries, but not which libraries to link.  On the command line, you would type, "-L/usr/local/lib", but you'd still have to type, "-lavutil, -lswscale" and so on, for each the libraries you want to link.  (There may be hundreds of libraries in /usr/local/lib.  You wouldn't want the linker to search all of them when trying to resolve some symbol.)

Comment: @saulspatz Edited, Added aditional steps to chose the filename

Comment: Thanks.  This doesn't work for me either.  This is what I meant when I said that if I typed the name of the library in the search box, the dialog won't accept it.  I never get to a point where I see a list of the contents of /usr/local/lib and just click the ones I want.

Comment: I edited the question to try to clarify what I was saying about the file chooser dialog.