# How to create a Client library to communicate with Turn Server in ios?

Tags: ios, c, xcode, cmake

I have created an app in which I want to integrate P2P with Relay server. So I am trying to use [Coturn Master](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) project.

I followed the steps below for creating Make File and successfully produced .a file from the CMake project.

In my Terminal from Mac OS, I used below commands.

1. `cd Project Directory`
2. `./configure`

Make file is generated after this command.

3. `make`

Which created a `libturnclient.a` and `turnutils_uclient` exe file.

Now I want to use this library in my iOS project.

I need a guidance about how to proceed ahead. As there is a C project already created in Coturn Master.

So how do I use that library and compile that Project from Coturn master to my iOS project?

Path in the project is `https://github.com/coturn/coturn/tree/master/src/apps/uclient`

Comment: If the library has been compiled for iOS then shouldn't you be able to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43071009/1707353)?

Comment: This library is built for Mac os. What changes should I make to make it compatible for ios?